# Transfer data from R to a specific sheet and a specific range of an XLSX file

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I am trying to transfer a matrix (or a data frame) from R to an MS xlsx file.

I know that the `xlsx` package does not provide a lot of options of pasting data to a specific range of an xlsx sheet (the only option I found is the  `addDataFrame` function which is difficult to handle) and at the same time its function of saving a workbook (`xlsx::saveWorkbook`) takes a lot of time.

Thus, I tried to use the `openxlsx` package and its `writeData` function.

Here is my code:

`WB = loadWorkbook(file = paste(Out_dir, Out_FN, sep=""))
writeData(wb=WB, sheet = "sheetName", x = Data, startRow = 11, startCol = 5, colNames = FALSE, rowNames = FALSE)`

where `Out_dir` and `Out_FN` are the directory and the xlsx file name where I want to transfer the data.

Although, when I use the `loadWorkbook` function I get the following error message:

> Error in grepl(target, commentsXML) : invalid 'pattern' argument

Any proposed solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: To debug your code, you want to break it down step by step. You get this error after the first line (`loadWorkbook`), correct? So something is going wrong in that line. Does `paste(Out_dir, Out_FN, sep="")` definitely lead to an existing file?

Comment: Hi camille, yes that's the line of the code that gives me the error. The file is indeed there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your code is the paste function for your directory. without the `/` in the filepath it is getting an error. If you save a workbook to your working directory called `Book3.xlsx` and try the below code. It should provide you with a working example of the openxlsx package function and ordering to produce your desired results.

```
library(openxlsx)
out_dir<-paste0(getwd(),"/")
out_file<-"Book3.xlsx"
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c("a","b","c"))
wb<- loadWorkbook(paste0(out_dir,out_file))
addWorksheet(wb,"sheetName")
writeData(wb,"sheetName",df)
saveWorkbook(wb, out_file, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I already checked this aspect and it is not the problem.

Comment: @Whitebeard13 here is a [github](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/365) link to the problem, I would recommend writing your matrix to a fresh excel and move it or copy it to your desired workbook.

Comment: @ Michael Vine Indeed the xlsx file in which I want to paste my data is full of merged cells with comments and maybe this is the reason of why R can't read it. I managed to paste the data with both the `xlsx::loadWorkbook` `xlsx::addDataFrame` and `XLConnect::loadWorkbook`, `XLConnect::writeWorksheet` but when I am saving the files (with the corresponding function from each package) I get a corrupted file plus the pasting changes the format of the sheet. So these are two additional impediments that I have to overcome.

Comment: @Whitebeard13 without your actual workbook I am unable to assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several options for you to consider.

```
library(xlsx) #load the package
# we'll assume your spreadsheet will be 20 rows & 8 columns
m <- (matrix('',nrow = 20,ncol = 8)) # '' removes NA from your final spreadsheet
# place values in specific cells 
m[10,2] <- c("B10") # as B10 is in row 10 and column 2
m[20,8] <- c("H20")
# export as xlsx
write.xlsx(x = m, file = "C:/your_path_here/Book1.xlsx",sheetName = "Sheet1", row.names = FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

## ########  ########

```
library(xlsx)
# load file contents
file <- "C:/your_path_here/Book1.xlsx"
wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
sheet <- sheets[[1]]  # or another
# data to put into B10:H20 range
data <- matrix(runif(7*11), nrow=11, ncol=7)
# modify contents
addDataFrame(data, sheet, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE,
    startRow = 10, startColumn = 2)
# save to disk
saveWorkbook(wb, file)
```

## ########  ########

```
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("C:/your_path_here/Book10.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name = "Sheet1")

# here, you can set the startRow and startCol. Col A = 1, B = 2,...
writeWorksheet(wb,x,"Sheet1",startRow = 10, startCol = 3, header = TRUE)

# automatically adjust column width
setColumnWidth(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", column = 3:4, width = -1)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

## ########  ########

You can write to multiple sheets with the xlsx package. You just need to use a different sheetName for each data frame and you need to add append=TRUE:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(dataframe1, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="sheet1")
write.xlsx(dataframe2, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="sheet2", append=TRUE)
```